Hamiltonian Circuit Counting and Classification Problem
the Problem Description
background
Consider an undirected complete graph $G_n$ with $n$ vertices, where if the numerical labels of each vertex are consecutive, then the edge weight between them is $1$, and the edge weight between the numerical labels on first and last vertices is also $1$. The edge weight between any other pair of vertices is $n$.
Classify Hamiltonian circuits based on the attributes of their edges.
Based on this property, consider a Hamiltonian circuit vertex arrangement $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$, which is composed of edges of weight $n$ and weight $1$, so its weight is $k \cdot n + (n - k)$, where $k$ represents the number of edges of weight $n$ in the arrangement.
For example, the arrangement $(1,2,3,4)$ corresponds to $k=0$, and the arrangement $(1,3,2,4)$ corresponds to $k=2$, because the edges $(1,3)$ and $(2,4)$ are not numerical consecutive, so there are $2$ edges of weight $n$.
Define the swap operation
Define the swap operation $c_{i, j}(H),i,j \in \{1,...,n\}$ to mean swapping the $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ vertices in the Hamiltonian circuit $H = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ to obtain a new Hamiltonian circuit $H'$.
Question I
Given the number $k$ of edges of weight $n$, how many Hamiltonian circuits have a weight of $k \cdot n + (n - k)$? In other words, the question can be transformed into:
How many Hamiltonian circuits contain $k$ edges of weight $n$?
Question II
For a given Hamiltonian circuit $H$ with $k$ edges of length $n$, how many swap operations $c_{i,j}(H)$ are there such that the resulting swap $H'=c_{i,j}(H)$ exactly increases or decreases by $l$ edges compared to $H$?
In formulization, the question can be transformed into:
$\#\{i,j\in \{1,...,n\}:w(c_{i, j}(H))=(k+l)n+n-(k+l),w(H)=kn+n-k\}$
where $k$ is the number of edges of weight $n$ in $H$, $w$ is the weight function of path,$l$ is the number of edges of weight $n$ that $c_{i, j}$ oprator reduced or increased from $H$
For example,$S_{-2}(4132)=\#\{c_{3,4},c_{1,2}\}=2$
the Progress on the Problem
Question I
This answer provides the exact solution to the Question I.
But the author didn't provide the proof for $a_r$, and I have spent a week thinking it but still have no clue (I'm not good at combinatorics). I would appreciate it if anyone could provide me with some hints.
Question II
I'm developing some trivial intuition regarding Question II that has been written in original problem page, but I am still far from solving it.
original problem link
